# Handling the UITextAlignment Deprecation on Xcode5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

I know it is feasible to Use NSTextAlignment as an alternative...but my app supports ios 4+ 
NSTextAlignment is available only from ios 6. how should i handle it for older version on xcode 5?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *versionComponentsArray = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

if ([[versionComponentsArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 6) {
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
} else {
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
}
```

Comment: how about making this changes on 400 location ridiculous right?

Comment: Use small logic of applying enum for label. Updated my answer in another. check it.

Comment: Please remove this duplicate and obsolete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
# define TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER NSTextAlignmentCenter
#else
# define TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER UITextAlignmentCenter
#endif

label.textAlignment = TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER;
```

Comment: i need to make changes on about 120 files,Is there way to reuse the macro?

Comment: if you have `Constants.h` file, then move macro to there and use `TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER`

Comment: @user2098116 You can write the macro in the prefix file, then it is available for every file in the project

Answer (score 1):

**NSTextAlignment** and the now deprecated **UITextAlignment** are both enums whereby -

```
 0 represents left
 1 represents center
 2 represents right
```

As this is consistent for both enums you could, rather than check what version OS and make unnecessary decisions at runtime, just declare your own typedef enum and use that instead, provided the three listed above are all you require. (*NSTextAlignment has additional enums that UITextAlignment has not got*)

Example - place in .h of where you need to use

```
typedef enum MyTextAlignment : NSInteger {
     MyTextAlignmentLeft,
     MyTextAlignmentCenter,
     MyTextAlignmentRight,
} MyTextAlignment;
```

EDIT: **NSTextAlignment** has been around since OSX 10.0 (circa 2001), and I doubt very much that 0,1,2 of the **enum** will change. Also if you have lots of files to manage you can put the **typedef enum** in its own header file, then import the header to your pre-compiled header (.pch) You'll then have access to it from any file and do a 'find and replace' accordingly.

Comment: mylabel.textAlignment =  MyTextAlignmentLeft is the feasible?

Comment: That's exactly the point. Because its an enum you could type myLabel.textAlignment = 0; This would work because it's just an enum. Not that I recommend punching in magic numbers as you want your code to be readable (hence the typedef enum I suggest).

Answer (score 1):

```
[label setTextAlignment:[self textAlignment]];


- (int)textAlignment
{
NSArray *versionComponentsArray = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

   if ([[versionComponentsArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 6) {
     return NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    } else {
     return UITextAlignmentCenter;
   }
}
```

Comment: But this creates compiler warnings? Right?

Comment: yeah, but we are handling it properly, So no problem while using it i guess.

Comment: For me it is annoying with compiler warnings. In what way "are handling it properly"? Please explain further (in your answer).

Answer (score 1):

to make the change in 120 or even more files,

1) make a category of UITextField
2) Over-ride setTextAlignment method as below, you can further edit it for left or right alignments as well.

```
-(void)setTextAlignment:(NSTextAlignment)textAlignment
{

  if (textAlignment == UITextAlignmentCenter)
  {
     NSArray *versionComponentsArray = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    if ([[versionComponentsArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 6) {
        self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    } else {
        self.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    }
  }
}
```

1. import this category in your project's .pch file,
2. Voila, thats all, you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I do t know about iOs4, but iOs5 handles NSTextAlignment just fine, I've just changed all my code over and my iPad first gen (5.1 I think?) handles it just fine.  Try it, it may just work